# Why is synchronous code inside asynchronously awaited Task much slower than asynchronous code

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have been playing out of boredom with retrieving random articles from wiki all at the same time. First I wrote this code:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await DownloadAsync();
}

private async Task DownloadAsync()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var result = new List<string>();

        for (int index = 0; index < 60; index++)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () => {
                var scheduledAt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("mm:ss.fff");
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"))
                using (var content = response.Content)
                {
                    var page = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var receivedAt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("mm:ss.fff");
                    var data = $"Job done at thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Scheduled at: {scheduledAt}, Recieved at: {receivedAt} {page}";
                    result.Add(data);
                }
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Process took: {sw.Elapsed.Seconds} sec {sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds} ms");

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

But I wanted to get rid of this async anonymous method: `Task.Run(async () => ...`, so I replaced relevant part of code to this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 60; index++)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => {
        var scheduledAt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("mm:ss.fff");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        // Get this synchronously.
        using (var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random").Result)
        using (var content = response.Content)
        {
            // Get this synchronously.
            var page = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var receivedAt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("mm:ss.fff");
            var data = $"Job done at thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Scheduled at: {scheduledAt}, Recieved at: {receivedAt} {page}";
            result.Add(data);
        }
    });

    tasks.Add(task);
}
```

I expected it to perform exactly the same, because the asynchronous code I replaced with synchronous is wrapped inside a task, so I'm guaranteed that the task scheduler (WPF task scheduler) will queue it on some free thread from ThreadPool. And this is exactly what happens as I look at returned result I get values such as:

```
Job done at thread: 6, Scheduled at: 53:57.534, Recieved at: 54:54.545 ...
Job done at thread: 21, Scheduled at: 54:06.742, Recieved at: 54:54.574 ...
Job done at thread: 41, Scheduled at: 54:26.742, Recieved at: 54:54.576 ...
Job done at thread: 10, Scheduled at: 53:59.018, Recieved at: 54:54.614 ...
```

The problem is that the first code executes in ~6 seconds and the second one (with synchronous `.Result`) takes **~50 seconds**. The difference gets smaller as I decrease number of tasks. Can anyone explain why they take so long, even though they execute on separate threads and perform exactly the same single operation?

Comment: ultimately, touching `.Result` on an incomplete task has **undefined behaviour**, and you **shouldn't ever do it**; it could be stuck on a sync-context, it could be waiting for the thread-pool to grow (which is at most one per second, from memory) - because all the existing thread-pool threads are blocking waiting on `.Result`, who knows?

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please expand on this or link some documentation/article? I didn't know that waiting for asynchronous code inside task can result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: HttpClient should not be placed in a using or instantiated multiple times unless 100% necessary. See ["YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE"](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @FCin I'm not aware of any - and it isn't explicit in the documentation - but: it is still true. The key risk is that in a scenario that involves a sync-context, using `.Result` will usually **deadlock** you. You're on the sync-context thread, and you block waiting for `.Result`; when the value is available, the completion attempts to happen, which needs to go via the sync-context - which blocks waiting for the sync-thread. Which is (as already stated) blocked waiting for `.Result`

Comment: @john Thank you, this code is only for fun. I was mostly interested in writing something asynchronous and `HttpClient` was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @FCin Fair enough :) I thought I'd let you know just in case - it bit us and was a little difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @FCin additional reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/08/28/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context/, https://olitee.com/2015/01/c-async-await-common-deadlock-scenario/, https://www.filipekberg.se/2013/04/03/dont-deadlock-with-async-and-await/, https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11463, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell "_You're on the sync-context thread_". I use `.Result` inside a task that gets scheduled on a separate thread which is not a SynchronizationContext thread(ManagedThreadId is different from the one that starts the application), so I don't understand how it can result in a deadlock.

Comment: @FCin even if it doesn't deadlock: you're tying up a thread unnecessarily - which is exactly what `async` is intended to **avoid**. So: using `Task<T>` but using `.Result` (on incomplete tasks) is essentially taking all of the overheads and none of the benefits

Comment: If you like to experiment you can `ThreadPool.SetMin/MaxThreads(1000, 1000)` and observe the difference. You can use Process Explorer to see the threads being created and TCP connections being opened

Comment: This is horrible code (  .Run(async void ), .Result, multiple HttpClient) , so any conclusions are off anyway.

Comment: "this code is only for fun" - benchmarking is hard. You should take it more seriously.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I wrote some code inside "Sandbox" application to pass time and see if I understand async. I experienced completely unexpected behaviour and decided to ask about it. `HttpClient` is a _detail_ that could be replaced by anything else. I didn't know that I have to follow some unwritten, strict, rules about writing code that I'm going to throw away in 5 minutes. Run async void is exactly the thing that I wanted to get rid of, because I understand consequences in case of exceptions. I replaced it and that's where I experienced unexpected behaviour. This is not production code!

Comment: Look at your question title. None of that is true.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What are you talking about? How is title of this question related to `HttpClient` or ignoring fact that `async void` will hide exceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because thread pool might introduce a delay when you request new thread, if total number of threads in a pool is greater than configurable minimum. That minimum is `number of cores` by default. In example with `.Result`, you queue 60 tasks which all hold thread pool thread for the whole duration of their execution. That means only `number of cores` tasks will start immediately, then rest will start with a delay (thread pool will wait for a certain time if already busy thread becomes available, and if not - will add new thread).

Even worse - continuations of `client.GetAsync` (the code which executes inside `GetAsync` function after it received reply from server) are also scheduled to thread pool thread. That holds all 60 of your tasks, because they cannot complete before receiving result from `GetAsync`, and `GetAsync` needs free thread pool thread to run its continuation. In result, there is an additional contention: there are 60 tasks you created, and there are 60 continuations from `GetAsync` which also want thread pool thread to run (while your 60 tasks are blocked waiting for result of those continuations).

In example with `await` - thread pool thread is released for the duration of asynchornous http call. So when you call `await GetAsync()` and that `GetAsync` reaches point of asynchronous IO (actually makes http request) - your thread is released back to the pool. Now it's free to handle other requests. That means `await` example holds thread pool threads for much less time, and there is (almost) no delay while waiting for thread pool thread to become available.

You can easily confirm this by doing (DON'T USE IN REAL CODE, for testing only)

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
```

to increase configurable minimum number of threads in a pool mentioned above. When you increase it to large value - all 60 tasks in example with `.Result` will start at the same time on 60 thread pool threads, without delays, and so both your examples will complete in roughly the same time.

Here is sample application to observe how it works:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        DownloadAsync().Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task DownloadAsync() {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 60; index++) {
            var tmp = index;
            var task = Task.Run(() => {
                ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out int wt, out _);
                ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out int mt, out _);
                Console.WriteLine($"Started: {tmp} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. Threads in pool: {mt - wt}");
                var res = DoStuff(tmp).Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Done {res} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Process took: {sw.Elapsed.Seconds} sec {sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds} ms");
    }

    public static async Task<string> DoStuff(int i) {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // web request
        Console.WriteLine($"continuation of {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // continuation
        return i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. It takes the same amount of time. I thought that ThreadPool would increase number of available threads automatically. But the question is, why does async version work?

Comment: @FCin well it will, but not immediately.

Comment: @FCin thread-pool growth is 1 per second - which is *very* slow in real terms. You're blocking up to 60 pool threads (because of the `for` loop), which fits your observed timing very closely (we can reasonably assume there were a handful of pool threads already - it isn't starting at zero)

Comment: @MarcGravell Absolutely agree on that. Times clearly show what the reason is, but I don't understand why using `async` works. How does changing `.Result` to `await` result in all threads executing at  the same time.

Comment: @FCin because when you `await` an incomplete task, that thread registers a continuation *and then returns to the caller*; if it gets to the top of the call-stack (which it does), then that pool thread is available to do whatever other things are needed, i.e. actually *doing* the "stuff"; when the results are available, the continuations then happen - again using the pool, but those threads are available and ready

Comment: @FCin I've expanded answer with more info and sample application.

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh, so if I understand correctly, async will schedule all tasks on queue instead of making new threads. And because they all were created inside task that means that each child task will be assigned to local queue of the task that created it. Is this correct?

Comment: @Evk Thank you, I understand the problem, but it is nice to look at it, how it behaves exactly :)

Comment: @FCin still last comment shows you are not completely understanding it. `GetAsync().Result` < current thread is busy. It does nothing useful but it's busy, not available for other work. It waits for result. `await GetAsync()` < current thread is free, available for other work. When `GetAsync` will provide a result in future - another thread from thread pool (can be the same if so happens) will run the rest of the method. So with `GetAsync().Result` a lot of threads are busy doing nothing, and that's bad for thread pool, because it's designed for short-time tasks.

Comment: @FCin so with async version, all tasks in question can be completed by 1 thread (in reality it's more, but 1 can do it theoretically). Thread thread runs until `await GetAsync()` for the first task. This takes no time, because only time-heavy operation is actual web request which it doesn't wait for. Now it's free. Now this same thread can run until `await GetAsync()` for the second task. Again no time, it can go to third and so on. Then when results are ready - it can go and run continuation (part after `GetAsync`). This also takes no time.

Comment: @Evk Yes, one thread(probably  a couple) goes and does all synchronous work (gets `scheduleAt`, etc.) and "fires" first async call for each task. These calls get finished on a separate threadpool threads and once they finish they return to the single thread that started them and it can finish the work going back to each task and finishing it. Correct? At the same time the single thread is free to process any other work. With `.Result` all 60 thread block each the whole ThreadPool.

Comment: @FCin well that's close at least. But "they return to the single thread that started them" is not quite correct. They don't return to other threads. When they are finished - they return back to pool (if we are talking about thread pool threads). Thread that created all 60 tasks is, as I understand, WPF UI thread. If so, when are tasks are completed (by thread pool threads), continuation of ` await Task.WhenAll` (all the code after this statement) will run on WPF UI thread, if you mean that.

Comment: @Evk Yes, I mean that the single thread picks up results after threadpool threads finish work and become available in threadpool.